# MariaDB retorna nulo com between datas

Tags: sql, mariadb

Alguém já teve esse problema depois que atualizou o MariaDB, parece que ele ignora o between... No meu servidor esses schemas retorna nulo não sei porque. Já aconteceu isto com alguém aí ? A versão do meu mariadb é 10.2.14

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=edff10999ed61077ce75687fb1137f49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz downgrade do mariadb e resolveu.